# Necessary to prove the inverse is Invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I am just starting out on linear algebra and I have come to a section the book that confuses me somewhat.

The authour defines an invertible matrix **A** as:
"A square matrix **A** is said to be invertible or non-singular if there is a matrix **B** of the same size such that
               **AB**=**BA**=**I**
Matrix **B** is called the (multiplicative) inverse of **A** and is denoted by **A**^-1 "

The author then goes on to prove the following proposition:
" If **A** is an invertible matrix then **A**^-1 is invertible and (**A**^-1)^-1 = **A** "

My question is: Is it really necessary to prove this? I think that it should be obvious from the defintion as the inverse **A**^-1 = **B** and **B**'s inverse is clearly **A** since
**AB**=**BA**=**I** is equivalent to **BA**=**AB**=**I** so you could just swich "**A**" against "**B**" in the definition?

Or does this proposition really need to be proved to be considered true?

**Edit:** Before the proof below the author had proved that **A**^-1 is unique.
However, he continues to prove that (**A**^-1)^-1 = **A**.

The authors proof that (**A**^-1)^-1 = **A** is the following:

" Let **B** = **A**^-1 then by the definition of the inverse matrix (above):
**A** is said to be invertible if there is a **B** such that **AB**=**BA**=**I**.

We know that **B** is an invertible matrix because **BA**=**I**. Required to prove **B**^-1=**A**.
By the definition of the inverse matrix we have **BB**^-1 = **I** and **BA**=**I**
Equating these gives:
**BB**^-1 = **BA**
Left multiplying both sides by **B**^-1 yields:
**B**^-1(**BB**^-1) = **B**^-1(**BA**)
(**B**^-1**B**)**B**^-1 = (**B**^-1**B**)**A**
**I** **B**^-1 = **I** **A**
**B**^-1 = **A**
Hence **B**^-1 = **A** which means (**A**^-1)^-1 = **A** because **B**=**A**^-1. Thus we have our result "

As you can see it is kind of long, at least I think so...

Comment: For the statement $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$ you somehow need uniqueness of the inverse. Maybe the author showed that?

Comment: It is sometimes hard to see the point of proving the obvious - but things are "obvious" once we have all the relevant information lined up in order - and that is what a proof is. There are many "obvious" things in mathematics which have proved to be untrue or surprisingly hard to prove, and where identifying the difficulty has led to major developments in mathematical understanding.

Comment: Based on your new edit, I think the author's proof that $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$ is overly complicated, if not pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you are saying, but I think one problem is this: how do you know the inverse of a matrix is *unique*?  It might not make sense to write $A^{-1}$ because this could represent multiple matrices.  The fact that the inverse of a matrix is unique requires proof, at the very least.  Here it is below:

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and there exist $n \times n$ matrices $B$, $C$ such that $AB = BA = I$ and $AC = CA = I$.  We want to show $B$ must equal $C$, and then that would mean the inverse of a matrix is unique (i.e., a matrix can't have two inverse matrices).

Well, $B = BI = B(AC) = (BA)C = IC = C$, and this shows that $B = C$.  Note that I used the assumptions that $AC = I$ and $BA = I$, and also that matrix multiplication is associative (i.e., B(AC)=(AB)C).

So, now it makes sense to call the inverse of $A$ as $A^{-1}$, because we know if a matrix is invertible, by the above proof there is only one inverse.

Finally, as you said, we know if $A$ is invertible, then there is a unique matrix $A^{-1}$ such that $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I$.  But this is precisely the statement we need to say $A^{-1}$ is invertible and its inverse is $A$.  So, you are right.  Once we know the inverse is always unique, the same statement that says $A$ is invertible also shows $A^{-1}$ is invertible and its inverse is $A$.

Comment: Oh ok thank you so much for that. However, the author proved that the inverse is unique before he proved the proposition that I posted above. So by what you are saying he really didn't need to do prove that the inverse of A^-1 is equal to A because we already know that A^-1 is unique?

Comment: @PandaDeTapas Yes, because what does it mean for a **square** matrix $A$ to be invertible?  It means there is a matrix $B$ such that $AB = BA = I$.  But we know if there is such a $B$, it is unique.  But then if $A$ and $B$ exist, the statement $AB = BA = I$ shows that $B$ is invertible since there is a matrix ($A$) such that $BA = AB = I$, and it must be unique.  So we can denote $B$ as $A^{-1}$, and then denote $A$ as $B^{-1} = (A^{-1})^{-1}$.

Comment: Alright I get it, sorry for being kind of slow but I'm not so used to proofs!

Comment: I guess you could say our argument (outlined in the last comment) *is* the obvious proof for the statement.  Is it obvious, as you said? Yes.  But at some point, when this material was being developed, those developing it had to derive this obvious proof.  All statements in mathematics require proof, except for axioms, which are statements you take to be the "building blocks" for your proofs -- they require no proof, and are very basic.

Comment: For example, there are axioms a set must satisfy to be a vector space.  Do we prove that a vector space is a set that satisfies those axioms?  No, we *define* a vector space to be a set that satisfies those axioms.  What we prove is: if we already have a set, and we want to show it is a vector space, we show it satisfies the vector space axioms.  But we never prove that a vector space *must* satisfy the vector space axioms because there is nothing to prove -- we define a vector space to be a set that satisfies those axioms.  They are our building blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is necessary, and in this particular situation it is obvious (as you said) that it is the case. After all, that is usually taught in introduction courses.

The point that this rather simple proof hides in plain sight is the need for commutativity with the inverse (**AB** = **BA** = **I**) for this result to hold.

In non-asssociative algebras it could be the case that  $ab = I$ but $ba \neq I$ ($b$ is called right identity of $a$ in this case.)

[Loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup) are an interesting case of non-associative structures which we are not sure when an element $b$ is invertible if  $ab= I.$

It is an interesting question to wonder why it is important to prove that, and it is equally interesting to understand why.

Hope this helps.